# Maximum of the product of increasing and decreasing functions

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima

Let's say I have two functions $f(x$) and $g(x)$ and they are defined only for positive values of $x$. $f(x)$ is an increasing function of $x$, while $g(x)$ is a decreasing function of $x$. Both functions are probability distribution functions, so their values are between $0$ and $1$. Their product $f(x)g(x)$ will have some maximum and it will go to zero as $x$ increases. Because, $f(x)$ will go to $1$, while $g(x$) will go to $0$, thus their product will go to zero as $x$ goes to infinity.

I am trying to prove the following statement:

$
\max  \left( f(a_1 x) g(x) \right) > \max  \left( f(a_2 x) g(x) \right)
$ for given $a_1$ and $a_2$ with $a_1 > a_2$, and $a_1$ and $a_2$ are positive numbers.

In other words, the maximum value of the product will increase with increasing argument of the first function $f(x)$. I couldn't prove this formally, although it seems quite intuitive. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: If the function $g$ is a probability distribution function it must be increasing also. What only matters is that $g\ge 0$. Since $f(x)$ is an increasing function of $x\ge 0$ and $a_2<a_1$ then $f(a_2x)<f(a_1x)$. Then the function $x\mapsto f(a_1x)$ is above the function $x\mapsto f(a_2x)\,.$ The rest should be easy. You may want to write $\max(f(a_1.)g)$ though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In fact, $g(\cdot)$ is a tail probability function. Sorry, I have put it as distribution function in the question. Thus, $g(\cdot)$ is not increasing function of its argument. But, I was able to find an answer to my question in this post. You might want to check it. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/287538/when-a-product-of-cdf-and-tail-distribution-is-increasing

Comment: You want to prove "In other words, the maximum value of the product will increase with increasing argument of the first function $f(x)$." Do you mean $\max_{x\ge 0}(f(ax)g(x))$ is an increasing function of $a$ ?